# Example $\text{Tor}$ computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. I'm trying to compute $\text{Tor}_n^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$.

**Attempt:** A free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ is given by (**is it?**) $$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$ I got this by considering the projective resolutions $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (respectively) and then summing them entry-wise. To compute $\text{Tor}$, I want to throw out the last term in the above sequence and apply $\_\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$. This gives (after some simplifications): $$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

First, $$\text{Tor}_0^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$$ For the other terms, I need to figure out what the middle map is after all the simplifications.

Am I on the right track? Have I made any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is fine. But, it might be simpler to prove some easy facts first.

1. $Tor_n(A\oplus B, C)=Tor_n(A,C)\oplus Tor_n(B,C)$.
2. $Tor_n(A,B)=Tor_n(B,A)$.
3. $Tor_n(A,B)=0$ for $n>1$.
4. $Tor_1(\mathbb{Z},A)=0$.

Using these, in your calculation, the only one that you need to calculate is $Tor_1(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ which you will see easily to be zero.

Comment: For the first fact, is there a similar statement for $\text{Tor}_n(A,B\oplus C)$?

Comment: Also, do any of these facts (namely 1) generalize to $\text{Tor}_n^R$ where $R\neq \mathbb{Z}$? Obviously 3 won't.

Comment: For  finitely generated modules over Noetherian rings 1. is true. Your first comment is clear using 1. and 2., since $Tor_n(A,B\oplus C)=Tor_n (B\oplus C, A)$ by 2.

Comment: @Mohan You don't need finite generation, Noetherianity, or anything: derived functors of an additive functor are always additive, i.e. preserve finite direct sums. In particular, $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A\oplus B,C) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A,C)\oplus \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (B,C)$ and $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A,B\oplus C) \cong \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A,B) \oplus \operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A,C)$ for any commutative ring $R$ and any $R$-modules $A,B,C$. Same for $\operatorname{Ext}^n_R (-,-)$

Comment: @user4355 Properties 1 and 2 hold for any $R$. Property 3 fails, as you point out (in general, the biggest $n$ such that $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R (A,B) \ne 0$ for some $A$ and $B$ is called the *Tor-dimension* of $R$). Property 4 has the following generalization: $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R (P,A) = 0$ for any $n > 0$ and any projective $R$-module $P$ (in particular, for any free $R$-module).